# Objective-C error... Cannot convert to pointer type (int)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am attempting to use the TouchXML library and followed the example with the following code

```
for (CXMLElement node in nodes) {
            NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            int counter;
            for (counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++ ) {
                [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
            }

            [rst addObject:item];
            [item release];

        }
```

The compiler however is complaining about `counter` and throwing the following error for `counter = 0` and both occurances in the `setObject` call.

Cannot convert to pointer type

Any help with my rusty C/ObjC would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, had nothing to do with counter, rather this...

```
for (CXMLElement node in nodes) {
```

node needs to be declared as a pointer like so...

```
for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
```